# Defining Erlang record in a module

Tags: erlang, record

I can define a record on the erl shell via:

```
129> rd(person, {name=""}).
person
130> #person {}.
#person{name = []}
131> #person {name="dummy"}.
#person{name = "dummy"}
```

But I'm not sure how to define and use records in a module.  When I create my_module.erl:

```
-module(my_module).

-record(person, {name, phone, address}).

#person {name="dummy"}.
```

...and try to compile, I get:

```
132> c(my_module).          
my_module.erl:5: syntax error before: '#'
my_module.erl:3: Warning: record person is unused
error
```

The documentation says rd is used in the shell since records are available at compile time, not runtime.  So I would assume I wouldn't need to use rd in the module definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined it right, but a record can only be used inside a function (when it's inside a module).

So add something like

`test_record() -> #person{name="dummy"}.`

Then you can see the results from the Erlang shell with

`my_module:test_record()`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a record in multiple modules, you can put it in a header file (e.g. `foo.hrl`):

```
-record(foo, {bar, baz}).
```

You can then include the header file in the modules you need it in:

```
-include_lib("path/to/foo.hrl")
```

Usually these header files are being put into the `include` directory of your application.

**Edit**: I quote from the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html):

> `include_lib` is similar to `include`, but should not point out an
>   absolute file. Instead, the first path component (possibly after
>   variable substitution) is assumed to be the name of an application.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> -include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").
> ```

So, it seems what I wrote is actually *more* true for `include`.